# JAVA Mail Stripping out double spaces from Subject

Tags: jakarta-mail

The issue seems to be related to the MimeUtility.unfold() method. When the subject is folded via MimeUtility.fold() it inserts a newline character if the subject exceeds the folding character threshold. Upon unfolding spaces are stripped out if more than one space is present after the newline. Below example illustrates the issue. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
String test = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa          bbbbbbbbbbb";

System.out.println("Subject Length Before Folding = " + test.length());

test = MimeUtility.fold(9, test);//As per MimeMessage.setSubject();
System.out.println("Subject Length After Folding = " + test.length());

test = MimeUtility.unfold(test); //As per MimeMessage.getSubject(); drops spaces after newline
System.out.println("Subject Length After Unfolding = " + test.length());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  JavaMail was trying to clean up the header by replacing multiple spaces and tabs with a single space.  In general, this shouldn't matter, and usually makes the header value look better if the header was folded using tabs instead of spaces to "indent" the continuation line.

But, strictly speaking, whitespace at the beginning of continuation lines should be preserved.

I filed a [bug](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8846), which I fixed for JavaMail 1.6.